# Why is this WPF Line not responding to a Style?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to get a Windows.Shapes.Line to respond to MouseOver or MouseDown or IsFocused--or *anything*, really. But so far, nothing happens.
I have a Style set up in a ResourceDictionary:

```
<Style x:Key="LineStyle" TargetType="Line">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Blue" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="Red" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="1.5" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and I also tried setting up the style in Window.Resources, but the location doesn't seem to make any difference.
I'm creating lines in code and applying the style but nothing happens. So then I tried just declaring the line directly in the window XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="PrimaryGrid" Background="LightSteelBlue" ClipToBounds="True">
    <Line Stroke="ForestGreen" X1="50" Y1="50" X2="200" Y2="200" StrokeThickness="2" 
        Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource LineStyle}" Focusable="True"/>
</Grid>
```

and I added some code that sets focus directly on the line, but still it never responds to the style. Other object types with similar styles work fine, with properties updating as expected. It's only the line that fails to respond.

It feels like I must be missing some fundamental setting that's particular to the class. Can anybody tell me what it takes to successfully apply such a style to an object of type Windows.Shapes.Line?

Comment: "*It feels like I must be missing some fundamental setting that's particular to the class*" - not at all. Dependency property value precedence applies to all DependencyObjects.

Comment: Based on the closed links, remove the `Stroke="ForestGreen"` and `StrokeThickness="2"` from directly in the <Line>. In the Style change it from `IsFocused` to `IsMouseOver` and your example will work.

Comment: Yep, that did it, thanks! For some reason I expected that the Style would override the local assignment. Forgot that it worked the other way around. D'oh!